# convert mysql query into rails query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Hi all I have a problem converting mysql query into rails query. 
I have these models -

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :comments, foreign_key: "commenter_id"
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commenter, class_name: "User"
end
```

Can anyone help me out with converting following query into rails query-

```sql
UPDATE comments 
INNER JOIN users on comments.commenter_id = users.id 
SET comments.deleted_at = users.deleted_at 
WHERE users.deleted_at IS NOT NULL
```

I am trying to make soft-delete comments whose commenter was softly deleted.

UPDATE 1:
so far I can able to do it by using this-

```
User.only_deleted.includes(:comments).find_each do |u|
  u.comments.update_all(deleted_at: u.deleted_at)
end
```

But I want to do this on single query without having to iterate over the result.

UPDATE 2:
I am using acts_as_paranoid gem, so unscoping user is needed and my final query became:

```
User.unscoped{Comment.joins(:commenter).where.not(users: {deleted_at: nil}).update_all("comments.deleted_at = users.deleted_at")
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying so soft delete comments when a user is soft deleted. Then I recommend in the action that soft-delete a user, to also soft delete the comments. `@user.comments.update_all(deleted_at: @user.deleted_at)` or something like that.

Comment: please provide models & associations details too

Comment: @Maxence I am trying to update all the comments from all users in one single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on MySQL:

```
Comment
    .joins(:user)
    .where.not(users: { deleted_at: nil })
    .update_all("comments.deleted_at = users.deleted_at")
```

This won't work on Postgres since its missing a FROM clause for users.

A less performant but polyglot option is:

```
Comment
  .joins(:user)
  .where.not(users: { deleted_at: nil })
  .update_all("deleted_at = ( SELECT users.deleted_at FROM users WHERE comments.id = users.id )")
```

This is still probably an order of magnitude better than iterating through the records in Ruby since you eliminate the traffic delay between your app server and the db.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I think this is what you want:

```
Comment.where.not(user_id: nil).each { |comment| comment.update_attributes(deleted_at: comment.user.deleted_at)
```

Or slightly more readable:

```
Comment.all.each do |comment|
  next unless comment.user.present?
  comment.update_attributes(deleted_at: comment.user.deleted_at)
end
```

Comment: I don't want to iterate on result since in large data-set it might caught an issue. So one single query without iteration is what I am concern about.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should execute number of queries corresponding to deleted_users and without loading User and any associated Comments in memory

```
deleted_users_data_arr = User.only_deleted.pluck(:id, :deleted_at)

deleted_users_data_arr.each do |arr|
  deleted_user_id = arr[0]
  user_deleted_at = arr[1]

  Comment.where(commenter_id: deleted_user_id).update_all(deleted_at: user_deleted_at)
end
```

Comment: You should at least use `.find_each` which will load the records in batches instead of exhausting the available memory and causing a crash.